# Replace dictionary values

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary, replace

Hey all, I'm trying to work on a simple script that takes a string and replaces each letter in the string. What I've tried doing is creating a dictionary for each values such as

```
mydict = {"a":"1", "b":"2"}
```

And I've tried some `for` loops but so far no luck. The idea I have in my head is for each value in the string, replace that value with what I have in the dictionary. But so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are doing is replacing one letter with another, simply use [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [`string.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate).

[Here's a pretty simple example of how to use them](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do something like this?

```
base = "foobar"
new = ''
replacements = {
    'o': 1,
    'b': 'x'
}

for c in base:
    new += str(replacements.get(c, c))

print new

>>> f11xar
```

reversed:

```
target = "foobar"
replacements = {
    'o': '1',
    'b': 'x'
}

for k,v in replacements.iteritems():
    target = target.replace(k, v)

print target
```

Comment: Is there any way to reverse this?

Comment: Hm this seems to print the same exact thing. I want to go back in forth in between text. I tried messing around with the for loop and changing up k and v in target.replace() but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Yes, same thing, but does it in "reverse."  You are going to have to be more specific.  "go back in forth in between text" doesn't make sense to me.  Can you give an example of what you start with and what you want to end with?

Comment: For example when I run this script I get `f11xar` How can I take f11xar and turn it back into foobar?

Comment: Jmariz: well, you change the target and replacements variables accordingly.  At this point though, I am pretty confused about what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: It's quite simple. If the first one takes me to f11xar, I want to take another function and turn it into foobar based on the dictionary.

Comment: just run the loop again using `target = target.replace(v,k)` but that will likely induce errors.  If the original target is "fooba1" then => f11xa1 => foobao.